# Does a gitignore prevent git from pulling files?

Tags: git, github

There are several descriptions for what a gitignore file achieves:

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore - [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
>
> From time to time, there are files you don't want Git to check in to GitHub. There are a few ways to tell Git which files to ignore. - [github](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

If files are untracked and are added to a gitignore file they will not be pushed to the server if I commit my repository.

What happens if I have files in the repository on github and they are added in the .gitignore. Will people receive those files if they clone the repository?

1. I would like to provide a default credentials file which shall be cloned into peoples repository but not pushed back if altered by said people.
2. I would like to provide a doc folder in the repository which should not be imported into eclipse if cloned.

Is git able to handle these two situations, and how would this be correctly set up?

Comment: Please be aware that committing does not push to the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is "no", or "maybe", or even "yes, but probably not the way you're thinking".  More specifically, `.gitignore` is only going to help indirectly, if at all.  The reason is that you can only ignore *untracked files.*  There is an alternative, which is to tell Git that *tracked files* should be treated as unchanged.  This alternative does not use `.gitignore` at all.  (I also don't particularly recommend it.

Many of these descriptions about `.gitignore` are vague and difficult to interpret because they don't start with the correct foundation.  The proper foundation for understanding `.gitignore` is Git's *index*, which is also called the *staging area* and the *cache*.  But before we get to this, we need one even-more-basic item.

#### Basics: commits, the index, and the work-tree

Remember first that what Git stores—the unit of operation, as it were—is the *commit*.  A commit holds a single snapshot of a file tree, along with metadata (who made the commit and when; their description of the commit; and some crucial *parent* commit information).  People like to think of Git as storing files, and that's not completely wrong, but in fact, Git is storing *commits*, and it's the commits that have the files.  Doing something with a Git repository generally means doing something with a commit.  Note that *all existing commits are read-only:* you cannot change anything about any commit.  (You can instead add *new* commits.)

The files in a commit, or in Git in general—this includes files stored in the index—are stored in a special, compressed, Git-only form.  These files are useless to almost everything else on your computer (including yourself) so Git has to extract them into a *work-tree*.  It's these work-tree copies that you can see, edit, use as credentials, and so on.

When someone clones a repository, they first get the commits—usually *all* of them.  They don't yet have an index and they don't yet have a work-tree.  So, as the last step of `git clone`, Git runs `git checkout` to *create* the index and the work-tree.<sup>1</sup>  This `git checkout` step selects *one particular commit*, typically the commit named by a branch name like `master`.  That commit stores a snapshot—a set of files—and Git now copies those files from the commit into the index, and then from the index into the work-tree.

What you have, then, when you first clone a repository, or use `git checkout` to switch cleanly to a new commit, is an index full of all the same files as are in the current commit, and a work-tree full of all the same files as are in the index.  The index exists because the commit is read-only, and the work-tree exists, separately from the index, because the index stores the files in their special, internal-only, Gitty format.

To create a new commit, you first work on the files in the work-tree, then run `git add` on some or all of these files.  What `git add` does is copy the files back into the index (converting them to the special Gitty format).  Eventually you will run `git commit`, and that takes whatever is in the index *right then* and uses that to make the snapshot for the new commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the index and the work-tree come as a pair.  If you use `git worktree add` to create a second work-tree for a repository, that creates a new index to go with the new work-tree.  The underlying implementation is a bit odd for historical reasons, but these should always be treated as a sort of mated pair.

---

#### Defining the index

The index, then, can be described as *what will go into the next commit you make*.  Initially, it has every file that's also in the *current* commit, and it gets used to populate the work-tree as well.  Over time, you change the stored data, and maybe even the set of files, and make new commits from the modified index.  So, at any given time, the index has a bunch of files in it.  The index copy of some file with path *P* will usually match at least one of two other copies of the files: the copy of *P* in the current commit, or the copy of *P* in the work-tree.

The initial state, as we saw above, is that *every* file in the work-tree has a copy in the index and in the current commit.  All three copies match.  You can read them all you want, but if you change them in the work-tree, you get into an interesting situation: **Git now "wants you" to `git add` them, to copy the updated versions back into the index so that they will be updated in the next commit you make.**

#### Work-tree files are either *tracked* or *untracked*

You can, on your own, create *new* files in the work-tree, that have no index entry.  Such a file is called an *untracked file*.  The definition of an untracked file is any file that is not in the index.  And, if it's not in the index, it won't be in the next commit either.

Note that what's in the index can change over time.  You could have a file that is in the index right now, and then use `git rm` or `git rm --cached` to *remove* the file from the index.  Now it's no longer in the index, and won't be in the next commit.  But in general these also remove the work-tree copies.

**You probably want untracked files.**  If you create a file in the work-tree that has no corresponding index and commit entry, this is an *untracked file*.  (Hence a file that *is* in the index and work-tree is a *tracked file*.)  But there's an annoyance with untracked files: Git keeps whining about them.

**This is where `.gitignore` files come in.**  A `.gitignore` file lists particular path names or name patterns.  Before Git whines about a file being untracked, Git checks the `.gitignore` files that apply to that path.  If the path is listed, Git simply shuts up.  ***This affects only untracked files.***  If a file is tracked—by which we mean if the file's name is in the index—then `.gitignore` does not apply at all.

#### The alternative is `git update-index --skip-worktree`

Note that the pre-condition for a file to be ignored is that it must also be untracked.  If it is untracked, it is, by definition, not in any new commits you make.  For it to *start out* as untracked, it must not be in the index made from the commit you check out with `git checkout`.  So it's probably not in *any* interesting commits.  (It may be in dull, boring commits deep in the commit history, for instance, but as soon as you check one of those out, the file is tracked, and when you switch back to a recent commit, Git *removes* the file.  So it's best to avoid this entirely.)

You can, instead, have a file in the index (hence tracked) but tell Git that no matter what happens to the work-tree version, Git should *pretend* that nothing happened, and keep using the index version.  You do this with `git update-index`, using the `--skip-worktree` option. (See also [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/1256452).)

#### Review, or, there's no *good* answer

If a file isn't in a commit, it won't be in the index when you check out that commit.  If you checked out that commit as the last step of `git clone`, you just made a *new* index-and-work-tree pair, so you don't have any untracked files at all.  The credentials file you want is simply *not there*.  You must run at least one command to create it.  (It can be pre-listed in the `.gitignore` file.)

If the file *is* in a commit, it will be in the index and work-tree, ready to use.  But it *won't* be marked "skip" in the index, so that if someone touches it, Git will tell them to commit it.  Adding it to `.gitignore` won't help because the file is *tracked*.  You must run at least one command to make it skipped.

**Either way, you need at least one command beyond `git clone`.**  I believe the better approach is to have template files that are committed, and to have the one command copy those templates to untracked, pre-ignored work-tree files, but the `--skip-worktree` variant also works.